# How to exit CoffeeScript REPL?

Tags: exit, coffeescript

I was trying to play around the awesome script - CoffeeScript in its REPL mode, but I found really hard to exit from it. I tried "exit", "q", "quit", ctrl + c, but still failed.

I'm using cygwin in Windows XP.

Anyone knows how to exit from it? Thanks!

Grace

Comment: Ok, I should have known that it should be same as Node.js REPL, which is ctrl + D.

Comment: Good to know. On non-Windows systems, both Ctrl+C and Ctrl+D will work (for both `node` and `coffee`). I can see why Cygwin wouldn't want "copy" and "kill process" to have the same keyboard shortcut, though!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If all else fails:

```
process.exit()
```